# how to establish a connection to a webserver in android?

Tags: android, http, authentication

I am working on a Http Connections.

I have a login form. When the enter a username and password. That values will be processed with the server and the user should be logged in.

Then it shows an users home page in a webview. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to do all this in a webview? Are your problems on the side of the server or the handset app?

Comment: in handset app i got problem.i am asking about when u login to some site then direct response to some link. i want to do that in webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question completely right, but you might wanna check out [this tutorial](http://devstream.stefanklumpp.com/2009/11/android-simple-httpclient-to.html) I wrote a few months ago. I hope that helps.

Once you got a positive response ("user logged in") from your http server you just open a new activity implementing a webview and opening that URL. Just keep in mind, that this URL will be publicly accessible, unless you add further security to it. But then it might be easier to implement everything withing a mobile website.

- [Simple HttpClient to send/receive JSON Objects](http://devstream.stefanklumpp.com/2009/11/android-simple-httpclient-to.html)